# Anatomically Correct Opticoid

Tags: biology, anatomy, bio-mechanics

#### Description

An [Opticoid](http://ben10.wikia.com/wiki/Opticoid) is an alien species from the tv series [Ben 10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ben_10) and is named and known for having green eyes with slits all over its body except for its head where there are two large bat-like ears. It is a bit taller than the average human and has a bulky physique. Its skeleton is made of cartilage and it has abilities such as eye beams that can be combined to create different effects.

[image: picture of Opticoid]

#### Question

Just out of sheer curiosity I was wondering how such a creature could (mostly about how the skeleton would look) function and what a more realistic look for it might be? (I am not so worried about the eye beams but an explanation would be much appreciated.)

Comment: "skeleton is made of cartilage" meaning it has no true skeleton then?

Comment: @Ash maybe not, but I'm just re-stating what the website says.

Comment: Sharks share it's pure cartalige skeleton, so there is president there (although none for land based creatures that I know of). Eyebeams are probably advanced bioluminescence/organic laser. As for eye placement... I would say that's probably the least scientifically viable part. Visual processing is like really hard and you aren't doing yourself any favours by having umpteen eyes that move relative to each other and are nowhere near the brain. (Possibly points to a distributed brain like octopuses?)

Answer (score 6):

The skeleton is easy - it is like a shark skeleton, but with a humanoid form.  Shark skeletons are made of cartilage and they work fine.

The eyes are actually commensal organisms.  This scheme is covered here:
[Could a disease make a creature begin to 'sprout' new eyes around its body?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/75852/could-a-disease-make-a-creature-begin-to-sprout-new-eyes-around-its-body/75860#75860)

[image: fly with many eyes]

Organisms have "homeotic" genes which kick off the development of organs. If you cause expression of one of these genes at a site, it kicks off development of the organ at that site.  Your Opticoid is infected with eye commensal creatures that have the homeobox genes for their special eyes.  Each commensal organism earns its keep by expressing the genes that cause an eye to form - useful for the Opticoid which is otherwise blind.   In the depicted fly the extra eyes are functional and so too the Opticoid.

This means no two Opticoid will have the same arrangement of eyes.  Some Opticoids might get overgrown with eyes and have to deal with the excess somehow.  Eye organisms might compete with other eye organisms for space on there Opticoid.  How they compete is left to the author.

Comment: Also any explanation on why such a large creature would had slits for eyes?

Comment: Where does it say it has slits for eyes?

Comment: in the picture of it

Comment: I think those "slits" are folds in its batlike ears.    It does not have eyes on its head.

Comment: the eyes on the arms and back have have slits not the ears?

Comment: Do you mean the slit pupils?  Lots of things have slit pupils.  http://www.koryoswrites.com/nonfiction/the-functions-of-different-pupil-shapes/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77775/discussion-between-amoeba-and-willk).